# Android radial menu increase radial redius

Tags: android

I want to implement a radial menu widget and i have used radial-menu-v4 jar. My code is as follows...

```
public class RadialMenuActivity extends Activity {

private RadialMenuWidget pieMenu;

public Activity activity = this;
RelativeLayout l1;
public RadialMenuItem menuItem1,menuItem2,menuItem3,menuItem4,menuItem5,menuItem6,menuItem7,menuItem8,menuItem9,menuItem10, menuCloseItem, menuExpandItem;
public RadialMenuItem firstChildItem, secondChildItem, thirdChildItem;
private List<RadialMenuItem> children = new ArrayList<RadialMenuItem>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.radial);

    pieMenu = new RadialMenuWidget(this);

    l1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.reltv1);

    l1.addView(pieMenu);

    menuCloseItem = new RadialMenuItem("Close", "Menu");
    //menuCloseItem.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);

    menuItem1 = new RadialMenuItem("1","j");
    menuItem1.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);

    /*firstChildItem = new RadialMenuItem("First","First");
    firstChildItem.setOnMenuItemPressed(new RadialMenuItem.RadialMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            startActivity(new Intent(RadialMenuActivity.this, TestActivity.class));
            pieMenu.dismiss();
        }
    });

    secondChildItem = new RadialMenuItem("Second",null);
    secondChildItem.setDisplayIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    secondChildItem.setOnMenuItemPressed(new RadialMenuItem.RadialMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            Toast.makeText(RadialMenuActivity.this, "Second inner menu selected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    thirdChildItem = new RadialMenuItem("Third","Third");
    thirdChildItem.setDisplayIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    thirdChildItem.setOnMenuItemPressed(new RadialMenuItem.RadialMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            Toast.makeText(RadialMenuActivity.this, "Third inner menu selected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });*/

    menuItem2 = new RadialMenuItem("2", "a");
    menuItem2.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem3 = new RadialMenuItem("3", "i");
    menuItem3.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem4 = new RadialMenuItem("4", "b");
    menuItem4.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem5 = new RadialMenuItem("5", "c");
    menuItem5.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem6 = new RadialMenuItem("6", "d");
    menuItem6.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem7 = new RadialMenuItem("7", "e");
    menuItem7.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem8 = new RadialMenuItem("8", "f");
    menuItem8.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem9 = new RadialMenuItem("9", "g");
    menuItem9.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    menuItem10 = new RadialMenuItem("10", "h");
    menuItem10.setDisplayIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);

    /*children.add(firstChildItem);
    children.add(secondChildItem);
    children.add(thirdChildItem);*/
    //menuExpandItem.setMenuChildren(children);

    menuCloseItem.setOnMenuItemPressed(new RadialMenuItem.RadialMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            //menuLayout.removeAllViews();
            pieMenu.dismiss();
        }
    });

    menuItem1.setOnMenuItemPressed(new RadialMenuItem.RadialMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            startActivity(new Intent(RadialMenuActivity.this, TestActivity.class));
            pieMenu.dismiss();
        }
    });

    //pieMenu.setDismissOnOutsideClick(true, menuLayout);
    int xLayoutSize = l1.getWidth();
    int yLayoutSize = l1.getHeight(); 
    pieMenu.setAnimationSpeed(0L);
    //pieMenu.setSourceLocation(200, 200);
    pieMenu.setSourceLocation(1000,1000);
    pieMenu.setIconSize(10, 20);
    pieMenu.setTextSize(10);
    pieMenu.setOutlineColor(Color.WHITE, 225);
    //pieMenu.setInnerRingColor(0xAA66CC, 10000000);
    //pieMenu.setOuterRingColor(0x0099CC, 10000000);
    //pieMenu.setCenterCircleRadius(40);
    pieMenu.setOuterRingRadius(600, 600);
    //pieMenu.setInnerRingRadius(100,100);
    //pieMenu.setHeader("Test Menu", 20);
    pieMenu.setCenterCircle(menuCloseItem);

    pieMenu.addMenuEntry(new ArrayList<RadialMenuItem>() {{
        add(menuItem1); 
        add(menuItem2);
        add(menuItem3); 
        add(menuItem4); 
        add(menuItem5); 
        add(menuItem6); 
        add(menuItem7); 
        add(menuItem8); 
        add(menuItem9); 
        add(menuItem10); 



    }});

    //pieMenu.addMenuEntry(menuItem);
    //pieMenu.addMenuEntry(menuExpandItem);

    /*Button testButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.radial_menu_btn);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //menuLayout.addView(pieMenu);
            pieMenu.show(v);
        }
    });*/
}
```

But I cant increase outer radius of the circle. I am using min sdk version 8. Please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using [this library??](https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Library-Source)

Comment: Yes i am using this library and try to increase circle redius by using pieMenu.setOuterRingRadius(600, 600); method....but its not working

Comment: then no change in the radius ?

Comment: It can change inner radius, center circle radius but cant change outer radius.....can you share your code?

Comment: Try with `pieMenu.setOuterRingRadius(600, 1000);`

Comment: I have tried this....it didn't work....i can change the color of the radial but cant increase width where my icons should been have placed...